# Is there any API for Non Max Supression on 3D bounding Boxes in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to apply Non Max suppression on 3D bounding boxes(Point Cloud). Is there any APIs in tensoflow like for 2D ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/non_max_suppression

Comment: @LeoGaunt That API for 2D, I am asking for 3D bounding boxes. For an example, [X,Y,Z,H,W,L,rot_yaw]